# Patching Jersey to use asm-4

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-datastore, jersey

this is a follow-up post to the twitter discussion i had on Google App Engine ([Twitter Conversation](https://twitter.com/app_engine/statuses/250863665442594816))

The Problem is that Jersey and GAE won't work together with datanuceleus 2.0, since GAE needs ASM 4.0 but Jersey needs 3.1. A detailed description and easy solution on that is available here: [GAE and Jersey Problem description](http://cloudvane.com/2012/09/23/problem-with-google-appengine-and-jersey-with-java/)

There are several posts on questions here on Stackoverflow, so I opened this thread to collaborate with Google's Teams to solve this issue.

I simply switched from Datanuceleus 2.0 to 1.0 and Jersey was working again. Do you have any other suggestions? Especially since 2.0 would be great to use.

Greetings,

Mario

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use version 1.18.1 of Jersey, which is no more dependent on asm 3.0 and contains a repackaged version of asm, you can check it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.18.1
This will work in GAE.

Answer (score 2):

You should try [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/), which embeds a jar into another jar and fixes code references on bytecode level.

See this excellent blogpost: http://blog.harrywye.com/post/30160964741/running-java-jersey-with-jdo-3-0-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

As @peter-knego said, with [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) is really easy, and you can still use JDO/JPA > 1.0

1. Download [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)
2. Create a text file: `testrules.txt` with the following content:

> rule org.objectweb.asm.**  org.objectweb.asm3.@1

1. With asm-3.1.jar and jersey-server-1.1.5-ea-SNAPSHOT.jar (or whatever you have) execute the following commands:

> java -jar jarjar-1.4.jar process testrules.txt asm-3.1.jar asm-3.1r.jar
>
> java -jar jarjar-1.4.jar process testrules.txt jersey-server-1.1.5-ea-SNAPSHOT.jar jjersey-server-1.1.5r-ea-SNAPSHOT.jar

And finally just replace the asm-3.1.jar and jersey-server-1.1.5-ea-SNAPSHOT.jar with the repackaged libraries.

I am using it with the 1.8.3 SDK and it worked to me.

Reference [here](http://blog.harrywye.com/post/30160964741/running-java-jersey-with-jdo-3-0-on-google-app-engine)